# How to control Arduino robot wirelessly?

Tags: arduino-uno, robotics, remote-control

I have a few potentiometers connected to analog inputs in an Arduino UNO. These are then processed and then the servo motors start moving to move the bot.
I would like to keep the motors with the uno and send signals from the pots to the uno. I do not want to use a laptop or another arduino as the remote control. However.. XBEE and other related stuff will do... Thanks

Edit- The wireless solution has to cover a long range preferrably 1 mile.(I dont think I will get any that will cover a mile but I'll give it a try.)

Edit 2- I have 8 servos and 4 potentiometer. I don't necessarily need an xbee. However it may be used.

Comment: Do you have *any* ideas of how to start this, or are you hoping someone else will do it all for you?

Comment: I have googled all over and nothing seems to address what I need.... BTW - I am 13 years old

Comment: Nothing will address all of what you need. Build it up piece by piece.

Comment: I think [this guy did something similar](http://millionbit.blogspot.nl/2014/04/io-sampling-using-xbee-apiadc-operation.html). E.g. XBee-PRO® 900HP has 4 ADC pins. Personally I'd use a second arduino to read the pots and send the data over e.g. IR. Cheaper that 2 XBees. Best of luck.

Comment: $150 will get you an 8 channel RC radio and receiver, and you will get about 3/4 mile out of it. Anything more will take a ham license to legally operate. Why would you use an Arduino at all?
http://www.ebay.com/itm/Spektrum-DX8-and-AR8000-/111651209735

Comment: @Spiked3 - an RC set like that is basically a 2.4 GHz transceiver chip and the functional equivalent of an Arduino, on each end.  The only real arguments against the poster's idea are the complication of DIY vs. an off-the-shelf solution, and the price/size/power premium of an Arduino vs. a comparable bare microcontroller.  NRF24L01+ won't have quite the desired range, but is used a lot in DIY projects of this sort.

Comment: @Chris Stratton  Oh, really? Well if is using 8 servos on a 6 pwm pin UNO he must be pretty smart, so ok.

Comment: There are *many* different solutions for doing so.  Remember you only need to output one PWM pulse at a time.

Answer (score 1):

A 13 year old programming an embedded device? Good luck to you, if you conquer it you will be years ahead of your age group.

What you need to understand are the fundamentals; how can you transmit a 'pot' over an XBee? That is an electronics question, start there. You will find that another arduino or laptop is probably required. The XBee itself requires some sort of host adapter, and it might as well be another Arduino since something has to electronically read the 'pots'.

Then you need to develop your own protocol for signals sent between the 2 Arduino (over XBee or on a serial wire , it is the same).  There are many already out there, but they assume you know the basics before you use them (eg firmata). This is the basics.

The fact that your google results showed nothing similar is probably a good indication it can not be done as you had hoped.

update: I like @gerben comment, but even as an advanced person, I would find it challenging.

Answer (score 1):

You can use so many methods to achieve it,as you are a newbie.i would prefer bluetooth and an android app.use bluetooth hc-05 module and use an android app to control.use this app and send string and control arduino.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.dzs.android.BLE_SPP_PRO&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way to do this without having individual wireless communication from each pot. There are boards that can communicate wirelessly that are small, however, most of these are around the size of a quarter developed by an electrical engineer. This presents two problems, first the wireless modules will be too big, second, you will need to do a lot of work before you have the experience necessary  to build something like this. I recommend changing a design decision.

Thus, in order to help you further we will need to know more information about your setup.